# Why python programs in my IDE or console run so slowly？How to solve？

Tags: python, windows, performance, intellij-idea, console

Now if I execute program in Intellij IDEA or Windows' console，sometimes the program will become very slow(slower 50~60 times than normal state!)，and I must change another computer to finish my task, this is very not convinient.

---

This is my benchmark program:
https://github.com/iHeadWater/station-simulator/blob/master/dijkstra_conda/dfs_path_test.py#L383

When in normal state, a cycle(writing a "stream")only use serveral seconds, but when it become slow, a cycle will spend for 5-10 minutes，and I'm sure cost of operations in the program should be stable(because I have run it for several times).

I minimized my console window(not only idea but also windows)but it has no effort,and it's Intellij IDEA which occupies the most memories (about 3GB), and `python.exe` occupies about 20% of CPU.

I don't think enlarge memory of IDEA can solve this, because the new computer which I run my benchmark program has only 1024MB memory.

---

I can't put `*.pstat` file as text on the website, so I choosed two screenshots of two cycles in slow state:
[image: The first slow cycle's pstat]
[image: The second slow cycle's pstat]

two screenshots in normal state:
[image: normal cycle's pstat]

And you can get my pstats in this link:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqtXP0NQgzvgrzJwWMC_zLne-yqq?e=GTf7Zp

This is invoke map's link:
https://postimg.cc/RN4HK4Hv

---

This is my system information：

```
CPU:    Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8300H CPU @ 2.30GHz 2.30 GHz
Mem:    RAM 16.0 GB (15.9 GB Available)
Windows Version: Windows 11 Professional 22H2 22622.586
Pagefile Size: 4096-8192MB
```

And I often use Windows' hibernate to close my computer.

---

This is my plugins' list:

```
ASM Bytecode Viewer
DBN
Pythonid
com.chrisrm.idea.MaterialThemeUI
com.demonwav.minecraft-dev
com.github.copilot
com.godwin.json.parser
com.intellij.plugins.html.instantEditing
com.intellij.zh
net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv
org.intellij.scala
org.jetbrains.kotlin
org.jetbrains.plugins.go
org.rust.lang
wu.seal.tool.jsontokotlin
```

Now how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you tell me why you are using INTELLIJ instead of PYCHARM. If its ok try PYCHARM may be it would help

Comment: In fact pycharm is only a plugin of intellij，I don‘t think change an IDE will make it better.

Comment: @forestbat Do you have plugins installed in your IntelliJ env, as per my experienc i had trouble with theme  and file watcher plugin ` Dark Purple Theme (1.1), File Watchers (201.6668.60), One Dark theme (3.3.4)` which once i disabled, i was able to jet my code.
Try disabling all the plugins.

Comment: @NishantPatel I have a material UI，and many other plugins. How can I export my plugin list and show to others？

Comment: @forestbat You can try this plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7891-plugin-importer-exporter to export the list. and It will mostly be hit and try to see any buggy plugin

Comment: @NishantPatel This plugin has expired and can't run Intellij idea 2022.2.3.

Comment: @forestbat Check for  "installed.txt" file is, it is inside the Settings Export file (default "settings.jar")

Comment: @NishantPatel I have updated my question and you can see my plugins.

Comment: @forestbat One outdated and buggy plugin as per my experience is com.chrisrm.idea.MaterialThemeUI. Do update all the above plugins

Comment: I banned MaterialThemeUI，but it's not effective.